# On Tumblr, video doesn't expand to fullscreen while inside masonry grid in Chrome, Safari

Tags: tumblr, jquery-masonry, vimeo, infinite-scroll, video-player

While looking at the Vimeo video post added with tumblr on this development tumblr account, please notice that when hitting the full screen button, the video does not expand to a full screen, but only occupies its own column. This same problem occurs even on each of the columns. A link to this error has been provided.

Problems experienced on a Mac Safari 6.0.5, Mac Google Chrome 29.x. 
The player plays as intended on a Mac Firefox 23.01

Is this fixable for Google Chrome and Safari on a mac, or is it a problem with masonry, infinite-scroll, or Vimeo embedded players?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Chrome and Safari when a `max-width` is applied to the `<iframe>` (or a parent). Unfortunately, the only way to fix it in Chrome is to avoid defining a `max-width`. The bug has been fixed in Safari 6.1 and 7 (not released yet).

Here is the Chrome bug report we filed: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=256247